# Server side sorting is not working in kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-grid, nopcommerce-3.80

I am trying to apply sorting on all data when i click on Name but sorting operation is applied on first page data.

Here is my code.

```
 $("#products-grid").kendoGrid({
                                    dataSource: {
                                        type: "json",
                                        transport: {
                                            read: {
                                                url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ProductList", "Product"))",
                                                type: "POST",
                                                dataType: "json",
                                                data: additionalData

                                            }
                                        },
                                        schema: {
                                            data: "Data",
                                            total: "Total",
                                            errors: "Errors"
                                        },
                                       pageSize: @(defaultGridPageSize),
                                       serverPaging: true,
                                       // serverFiltering: true,
                                       sort: { field: "Name", dir: "desc" },

                                    },
                                    pageable: true,
                                    sortable: true,
                                    editable: {
                                        confirmation: "@T("Admin.Common.DeleteConfirmation")",
                                        mode: "inline",
                                    },
 scrollable: false,

                                   columns: [
                                        {
                                            field: "Name",
                                            title: "@T("Admin.Catalog.Products.Fields.Name")",
                                            sortable: {
                                                initialDirection: "desc"
                                            },
                                            width: 300,
                                        }   ]
                                });
```

I have also tried with `serverSorting: true` but at that time default sorting not working.

Comment: the sorting is done for data that is display currently on grid

Comment: but i want for all  data not for current page of grid

Comment: why you need that

Comment: because i do not want to click again to sort in next page.

Comment: look into this example http://itq.nl/kendo-ui-grid-with-server-paging-filtering-and-sorting-with-mvc3/

Comment: I have used this example but i didn't work for me

Comment: THIS IS LIVE WORKING DEMO -  NOW FIGURE OUT WHAT ARE YOU MISSING   http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/y7kzK/

Comment: Sean Ch, i have already tried this and done as it but still not work

Comment: @Ajisha you SHOULD do serverSorting: true, And sending the correct response is server's responsibility not the client. Client will just bind whatever the data set sending from server end.